# Custom Same Page Search

Tags: customization, query, search, page-template

I've added a custom form to one of my page templates. It submits to itself `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in hopes I can grab the `$_GET` values and modify my query using `pre_get_posts`, but instead it goes to 404.

So to clarify, I don't want to use search.php, I want it to post back to my page template and modify my query to show the "filterd" results instead of 404ing.

I've tried using `pre_get_posts` to test if it's 404 or search, but I also don't want to stop anything else from 404ing.

So how can I use a query on the same page / url / page template without needing to reply on `search.php` or having my query cause a 404?

So with the custom search form in place the url is currently `http://mydomain.com/page-slug/?year=1111` - and I want to modify the query on the specific page depending on the `$_GET` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a query variable that is used by the WordPress Core. That is, [none of these](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars#Query_variables).

You are using `year`. WordPress will latch onto that and process the request according its internal systems. Try something more distinct like `hmg_year`.